# disptacher is null when npm link a local project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, rollup

I am developing a React component library which I now try to include into a local project for testing. I want to `npm link` the component library into my local project.
When I try this, I get the error

```
dispatcher is null
useContext@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37175:7
useTranslation@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:192272:63
ue@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68642:72
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:155248:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:158534:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:159830:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:144840:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:144884:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:144941:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:164815:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:164062:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163985:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163958:11
performSyncWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163650:38
flushSyncCallbacks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151680:26
commitRootImpl@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:164405:7
commitRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:164168:23
finishConcurrentRender@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163565:23
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163416:33
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:181381:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:181359:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:181596:25
```

This baffles me, because when I take the detour of bundling the React component library with `rollup`, publishing it to a private GitLab Repo and then install it via `yarn install` in my local project, it works. I am not sure what `dispatcher is null` is trying to tell me.

This is the `package.json` from the React component library

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@mui/base": "5.0.0-alpha.116",
    "@mui/material": "5.11.13",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^3.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.5",
    "@types/i18next": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.28",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.1.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.4.5",
    "react-super-responsive-table": "^5.2.2",
    "rollup": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^6.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of duplicated versions of react. According to the [docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react)

> This problem can also come up when you use npm link or an equivalent. In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts — one in application folder and one in your library folder. Assuming myapp and mylib are sibling folders, one possible fix is to run npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react from mylib. This should make the library use the application’s React copy.

I followed the quoted suggestion and the error was solved.